# How to get a value for the next year

Tags: r, dataframe

Considering the following dataset:

| **Company name** | **Year** | **Customers** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Company A | 2018 | 100 |
| Company B | 2018 | 120 |
| Company C | 2018 | 150 |
| Company A | 2019 | 120 |
| Company B | 2019 | 180 |
| Company C | 2019 | 80 |
| Company A | 2020 | 200 |
| Company B | 2020 | 500 |
| Company C | 2020 | 140 |

What I want to do is to measure the future return of the customers. So, I need to have the customer amount of next year in a new column. Something like this:

| **Company name** | **Year** | **Customers** | **Customers next year** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Company A | 2018 | 100 | 120 |
| Company B | 2018 | 120 | 180 |
| Company C | 2018 | 150 | 80 |
| Company A | 2019 | 120 | 200 |
| Company B | 2019 | 180 | 500 |
| Company C | 2019 | 80 | 140 |
| Company A | 2020 | 200 | NA |
| Company B | 2020 | 500 | NA |
| Company C | 2020 | 140 | NA |

Does anybody have any idea how to do this?

Comment: Are the tables sorted by year? Is it possible that years are missing? If years are missing take the next present year or use NA?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `lead` like in the following code:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(Company) %>%
  mutate(customers_next_year = lead(Customers)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 9 × 4
# Groups:   Company [3]
  Company  Year Customers customers_next_year
  <chr>   <dbl>     <dbl>               <dbl>
1 A        2018       100                 120
2 B        2018       120                 180
3 C        2018       150                  80
4 A        2019       120                 200
5 B        2019       180                 500
6 C        2019        80                 140
7 A        2020       200                  NA
8 B        2020       500                  NA
9 C        2020       140                  NA
```

#### Data

```
df <- data.frame(Company = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), 3),
                 Year = c(2018, 2018, 2018, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2020, 2020, 2020),
                 Customers = c(100,120,150,120,180,80,200,500,140))
```

Comment: Remember to add `ungroup()` at the end.

Comment: I think order_by might be needed in the lead function as well: `lead(Customers, order_by = Year)`

Answer (score 1):

A method without external pacakges:

```r
within(df, {
  customers_next_year <- ave(Customers, Company, FUN = \(x) c(x[-1], NA))
})

#   Company Year Customers customers_next_year
# 1       A 2018       100                 120
# 2       B 2018       120                 180
# 3       C 2018       150                  80
# 4       A 2019       120                 200
# 5       B 2019       180                 500
# 6       C 2019        80                 140
# 7       A 2020       200                  NA
# 8       B 2020       500                  NA
# 9       C 2020       140                  NA
```